# Java regex, unable to capture last group properly

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to parse few simple lines with **Java** regex:

```
[txt1] [txt2] [txt3] /some/long/path?params=1,2,3
[txt1] [txt2] [txt3] /path/
[txt1] [txt2] [txt3] /
```

My regex string is `^\[(.*?)\] \[(.*?)\] \[(.*?)\] (/.*)(\?.*)`.

I am struggling with capturing the last group - with my regex, only the first line matches the pattern but not other two lines. If I change my regex to `^\[(.*?)\] \[(.*?)\] \[(.*?)\] (/.*)(\?.*)?` then all 3 lines match, but the first line doesn't capture successfully (I get only 1 group `/some/long/path?params=1,2,3` instead of 2 `/some/long/path` and `?params=1,2,3`).

How to write this regex so that all lines have 5 matching groups?

Comment: what the output of each input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make you last but one `.*` lazy, make the last capturing group optional, and append the `$`, end of string anchor:

```
^\[(.*?)] \[(.*?)] \[(.*?)] (/.*?)(\?.*)?$
                                ^       ^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/D3hf5R/1)

- The `.*?` in the `(/.*?)` group should be lazy since we need to allow the subsequent group to be filled with as many chars as possible
- `(\?.*)?` - must be optional as the text can be absent
- `$` is necessary since the preceding 2 groups are optional, and thus no text at the end of the string might get matched. This way, we require the regex engine to grab the rest of the line.

See a [Java demo](http://ideone.com/rB0N91):

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^\\[(.*?)] \\[(.*?)] \\[(.*?)] (/.*?)(\\?.*)?$");
String[] ss = { "[txt1] [txt2] [txt3] /some/long/path?params=1,2,3", "[txt1] [txt2] [txt3] /path/", "[txt1] [txt2] [txt3] /"};
for (String s: ss) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()){
        System.out.println("Next match for \"" + s + "\"" ); 
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); 
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3)); 
        System.out.println(matcher.group(4)); 
        System.out.println(matcher.group(5)); 
    } 
}
```

Output:

```
Next match for "[txt1] [txt2] [txt3] /some/long/path?params=1,2,3"
txt1
txt2
txt3
/some/long/path
?params=1,2,3
Next match for "[txt1] [txt2] [txt3] /path/"
txt1
txt2
txt3
/path/
null
Next match for "[txt1] [txt2] [txt3] /"
txt1
txt2
txt3
/
null
```

Answer (score 3):

It is better to use negated character class in your regex for correctness and better performance:

```
^\[([^]]*)\] \[([^]]*)\] \[([^]]*)\] (/[^?]*)(\?.*)?$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/LdH3Cd/1)

Using negated character class, you don't need to use any lazy quantifier because `[^?]*` will match 0 or more of any character that is not `?`

[Code Demo](http://ideone.com/r3eHXq)